# FileStream security error

Tags: air, flash-builder, filestream, flex4.6, worker

I am developing multithreaded application in Adobe Air 3.6 with Flex 4.6. I am using FileStream class inside the Worker thread which is created in separate SWF file. When I declare the variable like this:

```
var FS:FileStream = new FileStream();
```

It throws the following error without any further detail:

```
SecurityError: file
```

Using FileStream class on Main thread works fine. Is there any workaround to this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
Set createWorker attribute 'giveAppPrivileges' = true.

_worker = WorkerDomain.current.createWorker(Workers.myWorker,**true**);
```